# data parsing from a file into java and then into a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have .Data file given in the above format . I am writing a program in java that will take the values from the .data file and put it in the buffer. MY java program is connected to Mysql(windows) via JDBC. So I need to read the values from the file given in the above format and put it the buffer like

```
Insert Into building values ("--", "---",----)
```

In this way, i store these values and jdbc will populate the database tables on Mysql(windows). Please tell me teh best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089754/groovy-reading-a-range-of-lines-from-file/4090166#4090166) for reading file lines and splitting them into chunks. I know the question says Groovy: but most answers are Java. Then insert the values you retrieved via JDBC.

Actually, since your data file is obviously CSV, you could also use a CSV libary like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read the values.

Comment: the files are in the .data format. Though, they are seprated by commas, but I cant change the name into .csv files. Please elaborate it

Comment: The file name is irrelevant, but CSV means Comma Separated Values, which is actually the case here.

Comment: CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv")); in this, .csv is used. But in my file, it is .data. I am not supposed to change it.

Comment: File names are just conventions, nothing more. Do this: `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.data"));` and it will work.

Comment: ok...let me try...plz be here for some time.I need your help .Or you can give me your email id so taht i can contact you there. Thanks

Comment: can I use arg[1] in place of "youfile.csv".....because while executing , I am putting the name of the file.And the name of the file is placed at 2 no. So,arg[1]. Would it work?

Comment: sure, it would work. beware: arrays are zero-based. args[1] is the second element of an array. Do you want that? If not, use args[0]. You need to learn some basics. Try the Java Tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: no, I am using args[0] for putting some othe file name that has the host and username, password to connect my mysql with java.But I am wondering, where I am storing the results after reading from the file.The format in which I have given you my data has that types of rows around 10-15. i guess, It would work.

Comment: I am learning java basics while doing it. practice is best way to learn.

Comment: *I am learning java basics while doing it.* Practice without theory is equally bad as theory without practice. You should really read a book or use the tutorial. Just learning by doing is a very rocky road.

Comment: actually I have project submission..so I dont hav much time to read it ...so I am just learning by doing it....anyways thanks for ur advice

Comment: sure. For this assignment, I agree. I'm talking about a larger scope. I learned Java by doing (had programmed PHP, PERL and other hacked up languages before), and it took me years to realize all the mistakes I was making. When you do have the time (perhaps after the assignment), follow the tutorial and read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 1):

The data is in CSV format, so use a CSV library to parse the file and then just add some JDBC code to insert this into database.

Or just call [MySQL CSV import command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) from Java:

```
try {
    // Execute a command with arguments
    String command = "mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: +1 for MySQL CSV import command (although I'd skip the middle man and call that directly, without any Java)

Answer (score 1):

This is the fourth question for the same task... If your data file is well formatted like in the example you provided, then you *don't have to split* the line into values:

```
Source:   "AAH196","Austin","TX","Virginia Beach","VA"
Target:   INSERT INTO BUILDING VALUES("AAH196","Austin","TX","Virginia Beach","VA");
      <=> "INSERT INTO BUILDING VALUES(" + Source + ");"
```

Just take a complete row from you csv file and concatenate a SQL expression.

([see my answer to question 1 of 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103740/parsing-data-into-tables-in-java/4104008#4104008) - BTW, **if** SQL INJECTION is a potential problem, splitting a line of values is not a solution too)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind your csv with java beans using opencsv.
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

you can make these beans persistent using an ORM framework, like Hibernate, Cayenne or with JPA which're based on annotations and map your fields to tables easily without creating any sql statement.

Comment: A bit heavyweight for an introductory programming assignment, no?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a perfect job for Groovy. Here's a [gist with a small skeleton script to build upon](https://gist.github.com/663880).